# how to get from a range of sequence numbers and rollover after overflow

Tags: php, mysql

I need to set an unique number with rang from 1-99 for each transaction, says,

- Transaction 1: seq_num = 1;
- Transaction 2: seq_num = 2;
- ...
- Transaction 99: seq_num = 99;
- Transaction 100: seq_num = 1; (rollover)

I am thinking to create a MySQL table named SEQ_NUM, with only field named 'id', so every time, I can run the following sql,

```
Update SEQ_NUM set id = id + 1;
```

to get an seq_num, if seq_num = 100, then I will set seq_num =1 and run another sql to reset id as,

```
Update SEQ_NUM set id = 1;
```

But I am not sure it is guarantee working, because there could be more than one transaction running at the same time, and before I run

```
Update SEQ_NUM set id = 1;
```

There could be another transaction asking for a sequence number, and the 101 will be returned.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the id have to be within 1 - 99?

Comment: That is just an example. But id have to be with a range and then roll over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the modulus operator is of use here. Perhaps the basic idea you have will work, but allow that SEQ_NUM to grow unbounded, and when you select it for your sequence number, wrap it in MOD().

But in reality, I would wonder if you already had a unique & auto-incrementing ID column which could be used this way (i.e. `SELECT MOD(id, 99) as trans_seq`)...

Comment: Thanks Ctrahey! So I can have an unique & auto-incrementing ID colum, so every time, I insert a record and it will return me a ID, and then I can MOD the ID by 99.

Comment: @Adam C: I'm going to suggest again, as ctrahey already did, that you do not need to store an id value that "rolls over". You can instead store a UNIQUE id value.  And from that, you could easily pull out a "rolled over" id value from that, whenever you needed it, using a simple MOD function. There is RARELY a real call to store an id value that "rolls over"; that approach usually causes way more of a problem than any problem it solves.